# How to add the recordid parameter to Group Invoice script

Tags: grouping, netsuite, suitescript, invoice

I am using a map reduce script to generate a Group Invoice. On the parameters, recordId(Document Number) is a required parameter. Since the script is running in multiple queues, how can i dynamically add the recordID?
here is the code snippet I am using :

var result = actionMod.execute({id: 'groupinvoices', recordType: 'invoiceGroup', params: {recordId: '2',invoicelist:invValues}});

How to pass the latest recordID

Answer (score 0):

It's all about how you structure the map.reduce script. I'm making some assumptions, but I think this should work for you.

```
function getInputData() { /** return all the invoices that should be grouped */}
function map (context) {
  // ... business logic to determine how you want to group this specific invoice

  // create the group if it doesn't already exist

  // write to the next stage
  context.write({key: invoiceGroupId, value: invoiceObject});
}
function reduce(context) {
  // each iteration of the reduce call will include all of your invoices grouped by the group ID
  var invValues = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < context.values.length; i++) {
    var invoiceObj = JSON.parse(context.values[i]);
    invValues.push(invoiceObj.id);
  }
  // trigger the action
  var result = actionMod.execute({
    id: 'groupinvoices', 
    recordType: 'invoiceGroup', 
    params: {
      recordId: context.key,
      invoicelist: invValues
    }
  });
}
function summarize() { /** do what you want here */}
```

Comment: If I hardcode the Recordid, all the queues will use the same record id and it will error out. I am looking for an alternative method.

Comment: Hi Anu, I made a mistake in the reduce script, because you would feed the recordId in the map function as the key, you can use that same value in the reduce stage to perform the action.